# IOS terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsarray

New to programming so apologies for any stupid questions.  There are no errors present within the code but it's from me testing out my App on the simulator.  I had just written a code where every time you click on a task it will change the color and move it below, i was so excited i kept clicking them and i clicked one that was already marked completed and had changed color and i guess my code wasn't prepared for that so no matter what new code i write i can just never get the app to run again without crashing.  See Code Below

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [[self arrayForSection:indexPath.section]removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationBottom];

}

#pragma mark - UITableViewDelegate

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    [tableView beginUpdates];

    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];

    // Tapped an uncompleted Task.  Must complete it!

    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
    NSString *task = self.tasks[indexPath.row];
    [self.tasks removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self.completedTasks insertObject:task atIndex:0];

    [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:1]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];

    }

    // Tapped a completed Task.  Time to make it an uncompleted task
    else {
        NSString *task = self.completedTasks[indexPath.row];
        [self.completedTasks removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [self.tasks insertObject:task atIndex:0];

        [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:1]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];

    }

    [tableView endUpdates];

    [self save];
}
```

Comment: You are accessing element at index 1, but array is empty. Print arrays to figure out where you do it

Comment: Read the exception message *very carefully*.  Then observe the exception stack trace, which points you right at the failing operation.

Comment: you all are awesome thanks for the reply.  I will keep searching and looking

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to access some inexistent data at one of your arrays.

```
[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]
```

is saying that your array has 0 objects, and you are trying to access the object at index 1 (no one). This is the cause of the error.

You should use defensive programming before getting or removing an item from any array.
Something like:

```
if ([array count] < index)
{
    [array removeObjectAtIndex: index];
    NSString *string1 = [array objectAtIndex: index];
    NSString *string2 = array[index];
}
```

Comment: I am making a beginner app class via web videos  and so while i understand some of what you're saying i'm scared right now to insert anything different and worry it'll change other things and get more confused.  I perhaps need to go back from the beginning and re-learn concepts because this should've helped me figure it out

Answer (score 0):

use [array count] this method check "completedTasks" is empty or not , U can't get data from empty array .